# How Can I search Django Multiple Tables with List

Tags: python, django

I want to search three models using forms in Django which are related by Foreignkey. And I also want to display a list of this search result with their respective details.
The idea is that, I have the following django models; Event, Ticket, and Pin. And I want to search using the Event name but I can't figure out what is really the issue with my code I am having error which says **Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Birth Day'** so below is what I tried,

Models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=False)
    event_venue = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event_logo = models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg', blank=False, null=False, upload_to ='profile_images')
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.event_name}"

    #Prepare the url path for the Model
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("event_detail", args=[str(self.id)])

class Ticket(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=PASS, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    added_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.event} "

    #Prepare the url path for the Model
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("ticket-detail", args=[str(self.id)])

    def generate_pin():
        return ''.join(str(randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(6))

class Pin(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=generate_pin, blank=True)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,  blank=False)
    reference = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, editable = False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Not Activated')

    #Save Reference Number
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.reference == str(uuid.uuid4())
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ticket

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["ticket", "value"]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.ticket}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("pin-detail", args=[str(self.id)])
```

My Views code

```
def Pin_Search_List(request):
context = {}
#Search PIN Form
searchForm = SearchEventTicketForm(request.GET or None)


if searchForm.is_valid():
    #Value of search form
    value = searchForm.cleaned_data['value']
    #Filter PIN by Events using Q Objects
    #event_filter = Q(ticket__event_icontains = value) 
    #Apply the Profile Object Filter
    list_pins = Pin.objects.filter(ticket__event=value) 
   
else:
    list_pins = Pin.objects.all()

page_title = "Search and Print PINs"
context.update ({
    'page_title':page_title,
    'list_pins':list_pins,
    'searchForm':searchForm,

})
return render(request, 'user/pin_list.html', context)
```

Please understand that the **searchForm** in the forms.py has not issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do

```
Pin.objects.filter(ticket__event__event_name__icontains=value)
```